# Bookmarking with eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

I really miss the bookmarking feature of Visual Studio + Resharper.
For example, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to toggle a bookmark, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to go to the next bookmark, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to go to the previous bookmark. I can even go to the next/previous bookmark in current file with some other key combination.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to setup it in Eclipse. Eclipse come with a menu name Add Bookmark which looks pretty weird (lame?) to me.
Is there any way to do bookmarking like what I described with eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard eclipse, this does not exist.
The only thing you can do is add a bookmark, and check out all the bookmarks in the bookmark view. For both actions, you can define shortcuts (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> twice and filter on 'bookmark').

However, you could search for a plugin which does what you want (for example: http://www.etc.to/eclipse_bookmarks_plugin)

Comment: Your example plugin is no longer available. The author must un-published the plugin, I believe. I'm looking for a similar plugin but google search doesn't help much.

Comment: It is available (I just tried it) if you use eclipse update site: http://eclipse.etc.to/updates/

Comment: In the available plugin list, I cannot find enhanced bookmarks plugin as advertised. Installing The Dom UI Plugin Set doesn't give me the bookmarking feature.

Comment: There were two things to install: the 'DomUI Plugins' and the 'editor tools'. Afterwards, you will need to restart eclipse.

Comment: Grhhh, checking "Group items by category" hide the editor tools from the list. I uncheck it and the Quick bookmark tool is available. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike good 'ol VS, you can't navigate to bookmarks in files other than the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Quick Bookmarks](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-bookmarks-plugin) plugin (free, fast & easy to install) from Eclipse marketplace. Then:

```
Add bookmark:              Alt + number 
Go to bookmark:            Ali + Shift + number
Switch between bookmarks:  Ctrl + N
```

Comment: No longer available - sadly